# c - too many values for a hex number

Tags: malloc, signed

Could somebody please clarify what's happening here that's giving me a hex value of 0xffffffa5 versus 0xa5?

```
#define HEXVAL 0xA5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numBytes = 3;
    char *tmp;
    char *pyld;
    pyld = malloc(numBytes * sizeof(char));
    memset(pyld, 0, sizeof(pyld));
    tmp = pyld;

    *(tmp) = HEXVAL;
    printf("out = %x\n", pyld[0]); // -> ffffffa5
 }
```

I was expecting "out = a5" instead of all "out = ffffffa5". I would like to add signed values to pyld so I'd rather not set pyld to unsigned char.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To begin, may I suggest using calloc? It formats the heap space for you.

To fix your problem, you have to make tmp unsigned. You can keep pyld signed. Just remember to deference tmp to print out the right value.

Here's my work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEXVAL 0xA5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numBytes = 3;
    unsigned char *tmp;
    char *pyld;

    pyld = calloc(numBytes, sizeof(char));
    tmp = pyld;
    *tmp = HEXVAL;
    printf("pyld = %X\n", *pyld); 
    printf("tmp = %X\n", *tmp);

    return 0;
 }
```

Here's the output

```
pyld = FFFFFFA5
tmp = A5
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Allen, thanks for your input, much appreciated. How would you handle a situation where there are 3 values to append and create 1 string. For example,

#define VALONE = 0x55

Comment: #define VALTWO = 0xA5

#define VALTHREE = 0xFF

I'd like to have a single packet that contained 0x55A5FF with a binary equivalent of 010101011010010111111111 or decimal of 5613055. Thanks!